# Need help to retrieve a Windows Certificate by Template?

Tags: c++, winapi, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I need to retrieve a Windows Certificate by Template Name (The Template is in the Extension Fields) using Windows API, C++.

My steps:

1. Open store: CertOpenStore(..) (Done; I can enumerate the certificates using CertEnumCertificatesInStore(..), but I see only their "Version 1 fields" and not the "Extensions". The Template is in the Extensions, so I cannot find it.)
2. **I tried to find it using the CertFindCertificateInStore(), but did not succeed. Can anyone help me with the correct find type and parameters or use another function?**
3. CertFreeCertificateContext(..), CertCloseStore(..) (Done).

Comment: `but I see only their "Version 1 fields" and not the "Extensions"` - you say that `CERT_INFO .cExtension == 0` ?

Comment: I mean I cannot see the Template name in the debugger. The CERT_INFO.cExtension == 9, which is correct for my case. But I don't know how to get the template name from the retrieved certificate, in order to compare it to my search string. In the debugger I cannot see the template name strings...

Comment: you need enumerate `CERT_EXTENSION` array and search for `pszObjId` which you need. then call `CryptDecodeObject(X509_ASN_ENCODING, rgExtension->pszObjId, rgExtension->Value.pbData, rgExtension->Value.cbData,..` for get decoded data and compare

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post my code, hope it helps someone.

```
void GetCertificateByTemplate(char *certificateTemplate)
{
    HCERTSTORE          hCertStore;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT      pCertContext = NULL;
    BYTE               *pbDecoded;
    DWORD               cbDecoded;
    _CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT *pbDecodedTemplate = NULL;

    // 1). Open Local Machine certificate store
    if (hCertStore = CertOpenStore(
        CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
        0,
        NULL,
        CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        L"My"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The store has been opened. \n");
    }

    // 2). Enumerate certificates
    while (pCertContext = CertEnumCertificatesInStore(
        hCertStore,
        pCertContext))
    {
        // 3). Check certificate extended data
        for (int i = 0; i < pCertContext->pCertInfo->cExtension; i++)
        {
            // 4). Decode certificate extended data
            if (CryptDecodeObject(
                X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].pszObjId,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].Value.pbData,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].Value.cbData,
                0,
                NULL,
                &cbDecoded))
            {
                ; // error !!!
            }
            if (!(pbDecoded = (BYTE*)malloc(cbDecoded)))
            {
                ; // error !!!
            }
            if (CryptDecodeObject(
                X509_ASN_ENCODING,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].pszObjId,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].Value.pbData,
                pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i].Value.cbData,
                0,
                pbDecoded,
                &cbDecoded))
            {
                pbDecodedTemplate = (_CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT*)pbDecoded;

                char* objectId = pbDecodedTemplate->pszObjId;

                // todo: check pDecodeTemplate->pszObjId

                // 5). Compare the template string with the search one
                if (strcmp(pbDecodedTemplate->pszObjId, certificateTemplate) == 0)
                {
                    // todo: return certificate
                    printf("\nCertificate template found: %s \n", pbDecodedTemplate->pszObjId);   
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 6). Free certificate, close store
    if (pCertContext)
    {
        CertFreeCertificateContext(pCertContext);
    }
    CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);
}
```

Comment: every time get `pCertContext->pCertInfo->cExtension` in loop. `pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension[i]` - very not effective code.
need `if (DWORD cExtension = pCertContext->pCertInfo->cExtension) { PCERT_EXTENSION rgExtension = pCertContext->pCertInfo->rgExtension; do {.. } while (rgExtension++, --cExtension); }`

Comment: @RbMm: It looks nicer, and I trust you that it is more effective. But, can you explain me why its more effective?

Comment: What's the best way to cast the BYTE* to _CERT_TEMPLATE_EXT* and check it? I was thinking of a dynamic_cast, but I see that it works only if the classes are related.